# ¿Porque mi foreach, siempre me da de indice 0?

Tags: php, laravel, base-de-datos, api, foreach

Hola tengo el problema de que quiero obtener el indice de un array obtenido por la base de datos pero siempre me devuelve 0 aunque tenga varios elementos, adjunto codigo...

```
public function delete(){
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');               
    foreach ($cart as $indice => $elemento) {
        

        return $indice;
    }
        
}
```

Añado el resultado del dd($cart);

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has un `dd($cart);` y añade que obtienes de respuesta

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo

Comment: @LuisLaguna Imagino que si el método se llama `delete` debes necesitar borrar algo... ¿será que esta faltando algo en este código?

Comment: @Marcos Si estoy haciendo un metodo para poder borrar un elemento del array en una sesion de carrito...

Answer (score 0):

Con esto

```
return $indice;
```

terminas la ejecución de la función actual y retornas.

Puesto que lo has puesto **dentro** del `foreach( )`, saldrás de tu función `delete` en la primera iteración ... justo cuando `$indice` tiene el valor `0`.

Si lo que quieres es obtener el valor **del último** elemento por el que iteras, basta con poner el `return` **fuera** del `forearch( )`. No hace falta ni que le pongas el *cuerpo*:

```
public function delete( ) {
    $cart = \Session::get('cart');

    foreach( $cart as $indice => $elemento );

    return $indice;            
}
```

Comment: Si bien el problema que plantea el OP se debe, como bien explicas, al `return`. Si necesita saber cuantos elementos hay en `$cart`, podría usar [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php) en lugar de un `foreach`. Si el método se llama `delete` creo que hay información que el OP debería agregar para saber que es lo que realmente necesita.

Comment: No tengo ni idea de lo que el OP necesita o quiere. Me limito a responder la pregunta según el código mostrado. La última vez que entré al recorrido se indicaba que este era un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, no de artes adivinatorias.